# Add a simple JS Alert Box on Post Submission

Tags: post-status

I want to add a simple Javascript alert box when a product is added by the customer for review. However, using the post status transition hooks, a white page is created after the popup. Is there a hook that fires after the page was reloaded? Here is my current code:

```
//JS alert on submit product
    function notify_me_for_pending() {
      $notice = __('Thank you for your submission. Your product will be available for purchase as soon as we have approved it!', 'pressive-child');
      echo 'alert("'.$notice.'");';
    }
    add_action( 'draft_to_pending', 'notify_me_for_pending' );
    add_action( 'auto-draft_to_pending', 'notify_me_for_pending' );
    add_action('new_to_pending', 'notify_me_for_pending');
```

Comment: Are you taking about backend or frontend ?

Comment: It's backend. https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

Comment: Search for white screen of death, and turn on wp_debug mode: that'll help you find what's causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when post is update WordPress redirect you from `/wp-admin/post.php` to `/wp-admin/post.php?post=41&action=edit` which mean it loads twice. Thus what you will do on transition status hooks that will be skipped before the content is printed.

**Solution:-**

- In transition hook callback function store (post meta) some flag to display js popup
- Bind a new function on `admin_head` hook
- Check if flag is there display the popup and reset flag.

Example:-

```
//Update post meta to display alert
function add_js_for_pending($post) {
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'trigger_notice', TRUE);
}
add_action( 'draft_to_pending', 'add_js_for_pending' );
add_action( 'auto-draft_to_pending', 'add_js_for_pending' );
add_action('new_to_pending', 'add_js_for_pending');

//JS alert on submit product

function notify_me_for_pending() {
    global $post;
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();
    //Check if we need to display alert
    if ($current_screen->base == 'post' && get_post_meta($post->ID, 'trigger_notice', TRUE)) {
        $notice = __('Thank you for your submission. Your product will be available for purchase as soon as we have approved it!', 'pressive-child'); ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <?php echo 'alert("'.$notice.'");'; ?>
        </script><?php
         delete_post_meta($post->ID, 'trigger_notice'); //Alert is done now remove it.
    }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'notify_me_for_pending');
```